# SRAM force axs brake judder/shake/vibrate

Tags: brakes, disc-brake

I have problem with my SRAM force axs brakes, I bought new disc brake rotors and as well brake pads, cleaned it all changed it, but yet when I brake it just totally judders or vibrates it just doesn’t brake 100% at all, I don’t know what to do already, I checked every single component and it’s all properly tight up under its torque. As well did bedding for the pads as I’ve ridden on the bike thousand km. Can anybody help? I have Giant Defy Advanced Pro. Last thing I’m thinking about is what if the frame is just defective, can it somehow affect the brakes in a way to cause these symptoms? I went to 10 mechanics, none can help.

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4XEn.jpg)

Comment: Has the brake ever worked as expected ?   Do you get the same results from front and rear brake identical ?

Comment: Ever since I bought the bike which is this year march it has same issue, and nothing has helped and worked to get rid of it. Yes front and rear brake have same problem.

Comment: Any other ideas what could be the problem? I will try switching other bikes front wheel putting it on my frame and see if the problem is still there and other way around, I will put my front wheel just to try on another bike so I could cross out some more stuff … all I can think of.. @Criggie

Comment: Its 6 months old, has never worked right, and you've taken it to 10 mechanics none of whom could fix it?   Take it back to the shop where you bought it and claim on warranty.

Comment: @Criggie I bought it from one guy who never rode he bike it was packed so i dont have anywhere to go and claim warranty… that’s why I’m looking for solution

Comment: Oh man this could be a tough one.   Can you add any photos of your bike?  That might help give us something to look over.

Comment: How or where can I add them on here? I will send some for sure @Criggie

Comment: @Criggie just added a picture of 3 days old front disc brake rotor, the bike is precise even not scratches, no other defects than thes brakes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar set of symptoms on a set of brakes a few years back. I was using organic pads and even when making sure the surfaces were clean and carefully bedding the pads in, the front brake would shudder excessively, especially at slower speeds. Wetting the pads would stop the shuddering and smooth braking would be seen, but soon the shuddering would return.

My eventual solution was to switch out the organic pads to a semi-metallic ones. Braking became smooth, predictable, and consistent. To this day I don’t know why the switch to semi-metallic pads resolved the problem, but if you are at the end of your rope on this problem, it may be worth a try.

Comment: Yes I have switched to both of those you mentioning, but yet it didn’t make the issue go away, it’s the same, I already spent fortune on it switching pads or blending them with metallic organic, nothing helps

Comment: Would you have any other suggestion? @tedhohl

Comment: @NatalieG. I wish I could offer more. I was hoping it was a similar solution, but I see you have already mentioned that you have tried this now. In my situation I was approaching my wits end as the bike was new, the original pads were not fouled/contaminated and the system was properly bled.  If I got the organic pads to work smoothly, one trip down the mountain (going easy on the brakes to not cook them) and the horrible shuddering would return. I feel your frustration, and I wish I could offer another suggestion that you have not tried yet.

Comment: thank you though, I think I will still investigate